# Keep Div visible after mouse moves from trigger (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently building a layout where I have several 'triggers' inside a `<nav><ul><li><a>` element - each display a `<div>` which effectively sits 'behind' (z-index).

I need the divs (#showme and #showmetoo) to stay visible even if the user moves the mouse from the respective trigger (.thetrigger, .thenextrigger) - as the divs will contain content/links.

Additionally, when the user moves from one trigger to the next the displayed div should change.

```
<header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="thetrigger">Show Me That Thing</a></li>
                <li><a class="thenexttrigger">Show Me That Thing</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>

        <div id="showme">Yay, this thing</div>
        <div id="showmetoo">and this thing</div>

    </header>
```

CSS

```
header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
            position: relative;
            background: red;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        nav {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 30px;
            z-index: 3;
        }
        nav ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        nav ul li {
            float: left;
            padding: 30px;
        }
        .thetrigger, .thenexttrigger {
            color: white;
        }
        #showme {
            display: none;
            background: blue;
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 300px;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        #showmetoo {
            display: none;
            background: green;
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 300px;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 2;
        }
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.thetrigger').hover(function() { 
                $('#showme').fadeIn(); 
            }, function() { 
                $('#showme').fadeOut(); 
            });
            $('.thenexttrigger').hover(function() { 
                $('#showmetoo').fadeIn(); 
            }, function() { 
                $('#showmetoo').fadeOut(); 
            });
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/richardblyth/24bcs/

Comment: update your fiddle to load jQuery for your js to work [LIKE THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/24bcs/2/)

Comment: Write less code - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/24bcs/4/)

It sounds like you want the div to remain until the next trigger is hovered over.

You can use a lot less jQuery if you use a class for the triggers, and find their respective divs using data. With this you can add as many triggers + corresponding divs as you like without having to write more jQuery.

HTML

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="trigger" data-show="pane1">Show Me That Thing</a></li>
            <li><a class="trigger" data-show="pane2">Show Me That Thing</a></li>
        </ul>        
    </nav>

    <div class="pane" data-show="pane1" id="showme">Yay, this thing</div>
    <div class="pane" data-show="pane2" id="showmetoo">and this thing</div>

</header>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){

    $('.trigger').on('mouseover', function(){
        // show the desired pane and hide its siblings
        $('.pane[data-show="' + $(this).data('show') + '"]').fadeIn().siblings('.pane').fadeOut();   
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually want, if I understand you question, is to hide the other #showme element when you hover into the trigger element associated with the #showmetoo element.

Like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('.thetrigger').hover(function() { 
    $('#showme').fadeIn(); 
    $('#showmetoo').fadeOut(); 
});
$('.thenexttrigger').hover(function() { 
    $('#showmetoo').fadeIn(); 
    $('#showme').fadeOut(); 
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/4N26S/

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

I just need to tweak it to accommodate some other (non-trigger) links in the nav but this is the fundamental behaviour I was missing!